# Dynamically creating arrays and compare them in c#

Tags: c#, arrays, for-loop

My basic requirement is of comparing some string arrays and then finding out whether they are same or not.

Basically i will get a count and based on that count i need to create arrays dynamically.

e.g i got count as 2 frm my query ,so i will need to create 2 arrays and access that arrays inside a for loop

Like in case of count 2

```
Arrays: string[] array0 = new string[100];
string[] array1 = new string[100];
```

and inside the for loop i need to access array0 when the index will be 0 and access array1 when the value of index is 1

```
here count = 2 suppose.
for (int i = 0 ;i <count;i++)
{
   when 0 then access array0 and when 1 then access array1
}
```

but i am not able to get the refernce of the array0 and array1 by this way.Can anyone guidel me to proper direction.

Thanks.

Comment: You need `string[][]` or `List<string[]>`

Comment: You should take list of string arrays instead of multiple array objects like List<string[]> arrays = new List<string[]>

Answer (score 3):

Try and store the arrays in an `Array`

```
string[][] AllMyArrays = new string[][count];
for (int i  = 0; i < count; i++)
    AllMyArrays[i] = new string[100];
```

this way you can index them overall array

Answer (score 2):

Something along these lines should work (untested, written in texteditor)

```
    public static void Main()
    {
        var arrays = GetArrays(5);
        var equal = true;

        for (int i = 0; i < arrays.Count(); i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < arrays.Count(); j++)
            {
                if (!arrays[i].SequenceEqual(arrays[j]))
                {
                    equal = false;
                    break;
                }
            }

            if (!equal)
            {
                break;
            }
        }

        Console.WriteLine("The arrays {0} equal.", equal ? "are" : "are not");
    }

    public static IList<string[]> GetArrays(int count)
    {
        Func<int, string[]> generateArray = x => Enumerable.Range(0, 100).Select(y => y.ToString()).ToArray();
        return Enumerable.Range(0, count).Select(generateArray).ToList();
    }
```

Comment: Better than mine (I think), but OP mentions needing to get an input integer and creating that many arrays

Comment: ah the question has been cleaned up a bit it was a bit confusing at first

Answer (score 0):

You can use array of string Array List of string list.

```
List<List<string>> lstOfList = new List<List<string>>();

int count = 2;
for (int i = 0 ;i <count;i++)
{
  lstOfList[count-1] would give you second list 
}
```

Comment: "You can use array of string Array List of string list.", erm, what?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you wish to allocate an arbitrary number of `string[]`. A `List` is good for this task.

```
  const int arrayLength = 100;
  var arrayCount = 4; // or whatever you collect from input

  List<string[]> stringArrays = new List<string[]>();
  for (int i = 0; i < arrayCount; i++) {
    stringArrays.Add(new string[arrayLength]);
  }
```

As far as the second part of your requirements are concerned, I admit I'm not 100% clear on what you mean regarding "finding out whether they are the same". I tried to wrap my head around it but your statements are too ambiguous. But this should get you on the right track.  :)

Edit:

Adapted Shenku's solution to something that I believe meets your requirements for testing if they are "the same".

```
  const int arrayLength = 100;
  var arrayCount = 4; 

  var arrays = new List<string[]>();
  for (var i = 0; i < arrayCount; i++) {
    arrays.Add(new string[arrayLength]); 
  }

  bool equivalent = true;
  for (var i = 0; equivalent && (i < arrayCount - 1); i++) {
    equivalent = arrays[i].SequenceEqual(arrays[i + 1]);
  }
```

`equivalent` stores whether or not all the arrays are the same. It's determined by [the definition](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb348567%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) of `SequenceEqual()`. If that doesn't work for you, there is an [overload](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb342073%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) that should.

Answer (score -1):

```
int count=2;

//create arrays dynamically
string[] array1 = new string[count];
array1[0]=1;
array1[1]=2; 

//access array using for loop
for (int i = 0 ;i <count;i++)
{
  Console.WriteLine(array[i]); 
  Console.ReadKey();
}
```